# Object required on Private Sub

Tags: excel, vba

this is my first post here. I was just writing a simple button to calculate my Experience on an Excel Character Sheet, and I'm very new to this, but I can't seem to find anything wrong with this piece of code. It keeps returning a "Compile Error: Object required" on line 2, and everything else I've looked at hasn't helped. I had the error a few times before, but it was an issue with how I was declaring my variables (I'm used to python)
If anyone could take a look at the code and maybe give me some tips, that would be much appreciated.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub addXP_Click()
    Dim addXP As Integer
    Dim oldXP As Integer
    Dim newXP As Integer
    Dim Lv As Integer

    Set addXP = Sheet1.Range("G4").Value
    Set oldXP = Sheet1.Range("A4").Value

    Set newXP = addXP + oldXP

    Set Lv = Sheet2.Range("G4").Value

    Sheet1.Range("G3").ClearContents

    If newXP >= (Lv + 1) * 1000 Then
        Range(Sheet1!A4).ClearContents
        Set Sheet2.Range("G4").Value = Sheet2.Range("G4").Value + 1

    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Whun using VBA, and trying to assign a value to a variable of type `Integer`, you don't need the `Set` before, just use `addXP = Sheet1.Range("G4").Value`.

You might consider using `Long` instead of `Integer`.

**Note**: using `Sheet1.Range("G4").Value` means using the sheet's `CodeName`, and not necessarily the worksheet with the name "Sheet1".

Try the code below:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub addXP_Click()

    Dim addXP As Long
    Dim oldXP As Long
    Dim newXP As Long
    Dim Lv As Long

    addXP = Sheet1.Range("G4").Value
    oldXP = Sheet1.Range("A4").Value

    newXP = addXP + oldXP

    Lv = Sheet2.Range("G4").Value

    Sheet1.Range("G3").ClearContents

    If newXP >= (Lv + 1) * 1000 Then
        Sheet1.Range("A4").ClearContents
        Sheet2.Range("G4").Value = Sheet2.Range("G4").Value + 1
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: @Ethan Seitter have you tested the code in my answer above ? any feedback ?